# For open source optimization solvers, the cutting plane algorithm is not effective in solving the scheduling problem of single machine

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, operations-research

The corresponding example in MIPLIB is [neos-3046615-murg](https://miplib.zib.de/instance_details_neos-3046615-murg.html) which is labeled as simple.

cplex、gurobi can get a better lower bound fast.

Is there an opportunity to improve the open source solver?

Relevant papers, recommendations or codes would be appreciated!

Comment: Not on topic. Please move to Operations Research.